# I don't have an address and I want to vote

Tags: united-states, voting

I'm registered to vote in California.  I'm going to be leaving my apartment behind to start traveling.  I'm not staying in any one state for long enough to count as a resident.

How do I vote?

(I'll be in Pennsylvania at the time of the election, but I'll have only been there for 11 days.  Everywhere I read says just to re-register, but I'm not eligible since you need to be in PA for 30 days to vote there.  I'll have lost my resident status in California after 15, and everywhere else I travel in the next two months will be roughly 7 days a state, first in Washington, then Oregon, then Illinois.)

Comment: @sabbahillel - That sounds like a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can inform your state that you will be traveling for an extended period of time and will want to maintain your residency as well as your driver's license and your tax status. You need to do that so you can continue to drive. Also apply for an absentee ballot since you will be traveling and not able to go to your polling place.

Comment: I wonder if this will work since I'm not traveling I'm straight up leaving?  Only one way to find out I guess!

Comment: @ZeeBashew If you are not establishing residence anywhere else, then you are "traveling". You should also arrange to have your snail mail forwarded somplace that you can arrange to receive it (if not directly then through a friend). Consider your bills.